# AJAX call in wrong order (async) javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a function that uses an API to get all information about all seasons of a show. Now I got the part working where i get all information, but all the information is in the wrong order. I have been looking around a bit on SO and I found out that AJAX calls were asynchronous and have been doing some more research. I still didn't find what exactly i have to edit in my code to get it working though. I tried to do something like this

```
function makelistbox(seasonnumber,count,slug) {
for (var o = 1; o < count; o++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api-v2launch.trakt.tv/shows/" + slug + "/seasons/" + seasonnumber + "/episodes/" + o,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "trakt-api-version": "2",
            "trakt-api-key": "ACCESSKEY"
        },
        success: function (response) {
            defArr.push(response);
            $.when.apply($,defArr).done(function(){
                AppendContent();
            });
        }
    });
}

}    
function AppendContent(){
console.log(defArr);
for(var u = 0;u<defArr.length;u++){
    select.innerHTML += "<option value='s"+ defArr[u].season +"+ e +"+ defArr[u].number + "'> s" + defArr[u].season + "e" +defArr[u].number+":" + defArr[u].title + "</option>";
}
}
```

but that didn't seeem to work since the ajax call seems to be done every time i reach the $when.apply... bit of code.

This was my original code

```
function listbox(slug){
$("#popupselect").empty();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api-v2launch.trakt.tv/shows/"+ slug  +"/seasons?extended=full",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "trakt-api-version": "2",
        "trakt-api-key": "ACCESSKEY"
    },
    success : function(response)
    {
        response.forEach(function (object,index) {
            makelistbox(object.number,object.aired_episodes,slug);
        });
    }
});
}
function makelistbox(seasonnumber,count,slug) {
for (var o = 1; o < count; o++) {
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api-v2launch.trakt.tv/shows/" + slug + "/seasons/" + seasonnumber + "/episodes/" + o,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "trakt-api-version": "2",
            "trakt-api-key": "ACCESSKEY"
        },
        success: function (response) {

            AppendContent(response);
        }
    });
}
}
function AppendContent(response){
select.innerHTML += "<option value='s"+ response.season +"+ e +"+ response.number + "'> s" + response.season + "e" +response.number+":" + response.title + "</option>";
}
```

My goal is to add every season episode with the season number and episode number and episode title to a listbox. I can not get this working in the right order..

Thanks in advance!

EDIT--EDIT--EDIT--EDIT--EDIT--EDIT--EDIT--EDIT--EDIT--EDIT

@Arg0n
Okay, i have been trying to do it for my seasons too but it doesn't really work out. From your code and the link i assumed i had to make an array from the ajax call of the seasons, so I did that ( basically that means i have a nested promises function right?). My code now doesn't give any errors but it doesn't work the way i want it either. Meaning my episodes are still sorted thanks to you, but my seasons still aren't

```
function listbox(slug){
$("#popupselect").empty();
var arrPromise =[];
arrPromise.push(
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api-v2launch.trakt.tv/shows/"+ slug  +"/seasons?extended=full",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "trakt-api-version": "2",
        "trakt-api-key": "ACCESSKEY"
    },
    success: function(response) {
        Promise.all(arrPromise).then(function(content){
            for(var z=0; z< content.length;z++){
                response.forEach(function (object,index) {
                    console.log("chec");
                    makelistbox(object.number,object.aired_episodes,slug);
                });
            }
        })
    }
}));
}
```

Comment: For one thing you know that you're response object contains more then just you're data correct? Usually you're data is contained in the response.data object usually there is response headers in there too so if you look at your response object it contains response.data response.headers  that kind of thing

Comment: It looks to me like you want to use `Promises.all()`. You can read up on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: But now my data isn't in response.data right? Because with "response. ..."  I always get the correct information. And actually I did know it but didn't think of it as needed, do i need to use my response headers somewhere? with like document.readyState?

Comment: I'll look into that arg0n :)

Comment: Possible to just set `async: false`, on the ajax call?

Comment: @VIDesignz That is not supported anymore

Comment: Oooohhh....good to know, thanks @Arg0n

Comment: async to false worked actually, just very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `Promises.all()` lets you do something like this:

```
var promises = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    promises.push($.ajax("SomeURL"));
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function(datas){
   for(var y = 0; y < datas.length; y++){
        var data = datas[y]; //Your data in correct order   
   }
});
```

It waits for all requests in `promises` to finish, and then calls the function in `then`. The result is a list with your data in the correct order.

**EDIT**

Translated to your code, this would be something like this:

```
function listbox(slug){
    $("#popupselect").empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api-v2launch.trakt.tv/shows/"+ slug  +"/seasons?extended=full",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "trakt-api-version": "2",
            "trakt-api-key": "ACCESSKEY"
        },
        success: function(response) {
            var promises = [];
            response.forEach(function (object,index) {
                var addPromises = makelistbox(object.number,object.aired_episodes,slug);
                for(var i = 0; i < addPromises.length; i++){
                    var promise = addPromises[i];
                    promises.push(promise);
                }
            });
            Promise.all(promises).then(function(responses){
                for(var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++){
                    AppendContent(responses[i]);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

function makelistbox(seasonnumber,count,slug) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var o = 1; o < count; o++) {
        promises.push($.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://api-v2launch.trakt.tv/shows/" + slug + "/seasons/" + seasonnumber + "/episodes/" + o,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "trakt-api-version": "2",
                "trakt-api-key": "ACCESSKEY"
            }
        }));
    }
    return promises;
}
```

Comment: This works fast and good, but now my episodes per season are ordered, my seasons aren't yet. I'll try to make it work for my seasons too now! thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah, that will be a good way to learn :). Please mark as answer and upvote of this helped you btw.

Comment: I did upvote it but i still need some more reputation first! it helped me though :)

Comment: Okay, i have been trying to do it for my seasons too but it doesn't really work out. From your code and the link i assumed i had to make an array from the ajax call of the seasons, so I did that ( basically that means i have a nested promises function right?). My code now doesn't give any errors but it doesn't work the way i want it either. Meaning my episodes are still sorted thanks to you, but my seasons still aren't.

Comment: I editted my question. You can see the code i wrote for my seasons there. Could you help me out a bit with what went wrong?

Comment: @Runey Hey man, sorry i did not see this until now. I would need the code calling `listbox(slug)` to see what i can do about this. You would probably need to `return $.ajax(...);` from `listbox(slug)` and put that in a `promises` array. Then call `Promise.all()` on that. Btw, remove `success` in your `ajax` and put this function in `then` of `Promise.all()`

Comment: @Runey i have updated the answer, hopefully this will get you in the right direction.

Comment: No problem at all, thanks for putting so much time in me! The problem is that the slug is actually the show name. The mechanics are, i push a follow button of a single show and thus a single slug, and I use that slug to get all seasons, so there are no multiple slugs. So what i actually want to do is do the ajax call first, so that I can do my foreach because i don't know how many seasons there are for that slug the way you did it. I think though that the way i tried it was pretty close? Unless i have to do the same ajax call twice so i would know the length..

Comment: function followlistener(texthover,slug){
    texthover.addEventListener('click',function(){listbox(slug);},false);
}
This is the code where i execute listbox, so I have one slug, with that slug i get all seasons, and for every season I get all episodes. These should all be ordered, so i get my first season => i get al episodes for that season, then i get my second season => all episodes for that season ...

Comment: So if i execute listbox(slug) i only get one response... that response contains all seasons, that's why i figured i needed to do a foreach? You say i should do a for loop getting the response length and putting that in a promises array then?

Comment: @Runey I think i understand where the problem was now, look at the updated code. It adds all `promises` for the requests for the episodes in a single array, and uses only one `Promise.all()` in the function calling `makelistbox`.

Comment: But the updated code would be completely wrong since it uses multiple slug while there would be only one, or do you mean that i have a nested promise.all() function?

Comment: @Runey The new updated code... Reload the page, i removed the "EDIT 2" and changed the code in "EDIT".

Comment: oops sorry, didn't see that. It works wonders now though! Thanks a lot! now i will analyze what exactly I did wrong because i seem a bit lost in the code now ^^ thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: The difference from before is that we add ALL the requests, for ALL seasons into one array (`promises`). Before we added ALL requests for the episodes in a SINGLE season to the array. That's why the order of the seasons got messed up, since you can't predict which season will get its episodes-requests back first.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways of doing it.

First and the easiest would be to make the AJAX calls synchronous but adding **async:false** to the jQuery ajax input. Thus your code would become

```
$.ajax({
    async: false, /*it's a synchronous request and thus SJAX*/
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api-v2launch.trakt.tv/shows/"+ slug  +"/seasons?extended=full",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "trakt-api-version": "2",
        "trakt-api-key": "ACCESSKEY"
    },
    success : function(response)
    {
        response.forEach(function (object,index) {
            makelistbox(object.number,object.aired_episodes,slug);
        });
    }
});
```

This will make the requests sequential however it will block the Javascript thread from proceeding and thus will block the UI rendering also.

Another would be to make the next request in the success or failure callback of first request, this too will make the requests sequential but it won't block the Javascript thread.

```
function makeAjaxRequest(slug, o) {
     $.ajax({
        async:false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api-v2launch.trakt.tv/shows/" + slug + "/seasons/" + seasonnumber + "/episodes/" + o,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "trakt-api-version": "2",
            "trakt-api-key": "ACCESSKEY"
        },
        success: function (response) {
            defArr.push(response);
            if(++o < count) {
                makeAjaxRequest(slug, o);
            } else {
                AppendContent(defArr);
            }
        }
    });
}

makeAjaxRequest(slug, 1);
```

Next method stores the callback request number and inserts the responses in a temporary array using this number as array index. Also it invokes AppendContent once all the callbacks have returned responses. Benefit of this method is that it is still asynchronous and doesn't block the Javascript thread.

```
var responseArr = [];
var responseCallbackCount = 0;
function makeAjaxRequest(slug, o) {
     $.ajax({
        async:false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api-v2launch.trakt.tv/shows/" + slug + "/seasons/" + seasonnumber + "/episodes/" + o,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "trakt-api-version": "2",
            "trakt-api-key": "ACCESSKEY"
        },
        success: function (response) {
            respnoseArr[o-1] = response;

            if(++responseCallbackCount >=count) {
                for(var i = 0; i < responseArr.length; i++) {
                    defArr.concat(responseArr[i]);
                }
                AppendContent(defArr);
            }
        }
    });
}

for (var o = 1; o < count; o++) {
    makeAjaxRequest(slug, o);
}
```

Comment: I only tried the first one so far, i'll try the others soon. The first one seems to work, but indeed very slowly so it's not recommended I guess :) Thanks!